# Java PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE encryption equivalent in node.js?

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I have inheritied Java web application and am supposed to convert that to node.js.

Part of that is encryption of data. In Java it is done like in attached code. How would I do that in node using crypto?

I am not strong in cryptography at all, sorry if this is really basic question and thanks in advance.

```
private final String ALGORITHM = "PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE";
private final int ITERATION_COUNT = 20;
private final byte[] SALT = {
        (byte)0xc7, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x8c,
        (byte)0x7e, (byte)0xc8, (byte)0xee, (byte)0x99
    };
```

and later...

```
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec("password".toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, ITERATION_COUNT);

// Create PBE Cipher
Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

// Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

byte[] encrypted = pbeCipher.doFinal("text to be encrypted");
```

Edit:
This is my failed attempt to implement that in node.js based on various searches:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var SALT = new Buffer('c773218c7ec8ee99', 'hex');
var pass = new Buffer('password');

//digest is by default SHA-1 thats what I need
var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(pass, SALT, 20, 56); //[, digest]
//var cipher = crypto.createCipher('des-ede-cbc', key);
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('des-ede', key);
//var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede-cbc', key, new Buffer('00000000', 'binary'));
cipher.update(new Buffer('This is to be encoded'));
var encrypted = cipher.final('binary');
console.log(encrypted);
fs.writeFileSync('encrypted.file', encrypted);
```

When I am trying to use `crypto.createCipheriv` I have no idea what to put there as IV.

When used without IV, it produces some 'encrypted' gibberish however when saved to file, it can't be read and decoded on Java side. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you can't get these to interoperate is the Java side is using `PBE` and the node.js side is using `PBKDF2`, which serve similar purposes and come from the same standards document (PKCS #5), but have very different mechanisms under the hood.

Because these are different key generation algorithms, you generate different keys on each end, and thus get different results when you decrypt.

There is also something of an mismatch in the level of abstraction between java and node.js in your code.  the Java API you are using is very high level, and uses OpenSSL-like constructs.  Meanwhile, the node.js code is at a much lower level, gluing pieces together bit-by-bit.  This can cause issues when, for example, the java code introduces a particular padding structure or cipher mode of operation.

If this is just for learning or something non-critical, I would recommend changing the java code to be at the same lower level as the node.js code, and put pieces together one by one: generate the key on both sides and make sure they are the same, ecrypt on both sides and get the same output, etc.  If you can't change the java code, use something like [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) to get your node.js code at the same higher level as the java code.  But as the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22223043/1904979) indicate, you may not be able to do PBE anyways.

If this is for something "real" where you actually want the files saved to be secure, call out to an external program like gpg to handle the encryption, instead of "rolling your own" file encryption system.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate reply. Unfortunately this is not school homework or something similar, it is live system and the worst part is I can't change the Java (decryption) part. After reading your reply l have decided to write the encryption part in Java and nodejs spawns that as process. It works well but it is terrible, desperate solution. Either way, thanks.