# AES Decryption from java to nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, encryption

I'm working on a piece of code which encrypt data in Java, and I need to decrypt it in nodejs. I am having issues with the decryption.

I'm adding the salt + the encrypted bytes all together and encode them in base64 in the java side.

on the node side i'm decoding base64, then slicing the salt and encrypted bytes. but i'm getting an error while trying to decrypt the string. any ideas?

Java encrypt:

```
private Key createKey(final byte[] salt) {
    final PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(KEY,
                                           salt,
                                           20000,
                                           256);
    final SecretKey secretKey;
    secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(spec);        
    return new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), 'AES');
  }

public String encrypt(final String message) {
    final byte[] salt = secureRandom.nextBytes(SALT_LENGTH);
    final Key key = createKey(salt);

    final Cipher encryptingCipher = createCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, salt);
    final byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final byte[] encryptedBytes = doFinal(encryptingCipher, messageBytes);
    final byte[] data = ArrayUtils.addAll(salt, encryptedBytes);
    return BaseEncoding.base64().encode(data);
  }
```

Nodejs decrypt:

```
 const decrypted = new Buffer(data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    const salt = decrypted.slice(0, AESEncryptor.SALT_LENGTH);
    const encryptedBytes = decrypted.slice(AESEncryptor.SALT_LENGTH);

    crypto.pbkdf2(KEY, salt, 20000, 256, (err, key) => {
      var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, salt);
      var decoded = decipher.update(encryptedBytes, 'binary', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
      console.log('decoded', decoded);
    });
```

That's the error i'm getting:

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35050164/1816580) for a very similar approach. Please add the components you've chosen (AES & SHA256?).

Comment: @ArtjomB. ofcourse I was looking for answers over the net before asking. It didn't help me. and yes I am using AES & SHA256

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the missing information like `Cipher.getInstance()` string and which key factory you're using. Then you should show example inputs and outputs for both code snippets.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Any comment on using the PBKDF2 salt as the iv? I don't see an issue but I may be overlooking something. Neither did my SME but that person is not a cryptologist, just a cryptographer.

Comment: @zaph I think it's fine as long as the key derivation with a random salt is done for each encryption and it's not cached for multiple encryptions, but Ilmari Karonen has a [valid different view](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31831/13022).